# How to select data after autofilter? UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) not working

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet of data. I apply the autofilter. Now, I want to copy and paste that particular data only the visible lines. I'm using the command UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy and it is now working. Is there any other way to do this? or a workaround?

this is my code

```
ws1.Activate
ws1.Cells(1, 1).Select

'to count how many lines are on the sheet
LastRow = ws1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

'lets use the last row to build the range that I need to filter
myrange = CStr(LastRow)


'I filter the range on the sheet by 0.14
ws1.Range("A1:O" & myrange).AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="0.14"


'this counts the data(rows) visible after applying the filter and -1 means minus the header
Rowz = ws1.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1

'this will copy the filtered data into the following range
'I get the error in this line of code. dont know what wrong 
ws1.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Range("A" & CStr(LastRow + 1) & ":O" & CStr(LastRow + 1))

'I tried as well
ws1.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Range("A" & CStr(LastRow + 1) & ":O" & CStr(LastRow + 1 + Rowz))
```

any ideas are welcome :)

Comment: "Not working" as in.... what, exactly? You're providing an unqualified `Range` for a destination, which means you're pasting on whatever the `ActiveSheet` is, ...and that appears to be your `ws1` sheet.

Comment: All you need after you have filtered your data is to use this one line. `.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy.`, then select the cell in your destination worksheet to paste, i.e. `Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("F1")`